# How to show native google map in webview in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview

I have the following code to show webview :

**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**WebViewActivity.java**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" +"saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
    }
}
```

**I want to open following code in WebView:**

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355"));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
"com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What exactly you want to do because you question is a bit confusing me

Comment: Just want to open the last part of code above in webview !!

Comment: Hi captainpirate,I have the same issue.if you have solved this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3).It does not open native Google Map app in WebView instead it loads http://maps.google.com/maps?~~ in WebView.

May Help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps";

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.equals("http://maps.google.com/maps")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355"));
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            //else part
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: displays just a white screen !!

Comment: Did you get a Google Map API key and the related XML code from here http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

Comment: I dont use MapActivity here, why do i need Google Map API key ? If needed where should i put the api key ? My Complete class code is above.

Comment: I gave the code for a normal Activity class. It is working if you have given the **android.permission.INTERNET** in the Manifest. The above link is for WebView. That's all I can help.